# Simple image processing very slow

Tags: image-processing, replacement, image

I have compared the speed of some simple image processing routines between Mathematica an IDL.

**1. Reading of a grey scale png image of (720,577) pixels:**

The image is:

[image]

**Mathematica:**

```
t1 = AbsoluteTime[];
img = Import[filename];
Print[AbsoluteTime[] - t1]
0.029513
```

**IDL:**

```
t1=systime(1)
img=read_png(filename)
print,systime(1)-t1
0.013546944
```

IDL is giving the byte array of pixel values of the image.

To do that in addition with Mathematica:

```
t1 = AbsoluteTime[];
imgData = ImageData[img, "Byte"];
Print[AbsoluteTime[] - t1]
0.002133
```

costs another few msec.

**---> IDL is about 2 times faster**

**2. Finding positions of pixels at which the image pixels are exceeding a threshold of 50:**

**Mathematica:**

```
t1 = AbsoluteTime[];
is = Position[imgData, n_ /; n >= 50];
Print[AbsoluteTime[] - t1]
0.222408
```

**IDL:**

```
t1=systime(1)
is=where(img GE 50)
print,systime(1)-t1
0.00085401535
```

**---> IDL is more than 250 times faster**

**3. Replacing the pixel values that exceed the threshold of 50 with 255:**

**Mathematica:**

```
t1 = AbsoluteTime[];
img = ReplacePart[imgData, is -> 255];
Print[AbsoluteTime[] - t1]
0.080377
```

**IDL:**

```
t1=systime(1)
img(is)=255
print,systime(1)-t1
3.2901764e-05
```

**---> IDL is nearly 2500 times faster**

These differences are really disappointing.

I would be happy if somebody has a solution how to do the things faster.

Comment: If you are working with grayscale, then you process each pixel three times for RGB - same with replace.

Comment: For finding the positions this should be quite fast: `SparseArray[UnitStep[imgData - 50]]["NonzeroPositions"]`

Comment: `ImageApply[Min[{#, 255}] &, img] // AbsoluteTiming` can do the last two quickly.

Comment: I think you should change the title/description, to be honest. Neither `Import`, `Position` or `ReplacePart` are image processing routines. You should rather be asking, "how can I do this with image processing routines?" or "how can I make this code faster?"

Comment: Thank you for this hint and for your help ...

Answer (score 12):

All three parts of this operation can be done in 0.026 seconds:

```
In[3]:= AbsoluteTiming[ImageAdd[img, Binarize[img = Import[filename, "PNG"], {50/255, 1}]];]
Out[3]= {0.026024, Null}
```

`PixelValuePositions` can be used for extracting pixel positions:

```
In[1]:= img = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/uye1v.png"];
AbsoluteTiming[bimg = Binarize[img, {50/255, 1}];]
AbsoluteTiming[pos = PixelValuePositions[bimg, 1];]
Out[2]= {0.001001, Null}
Out[3]= {0.004005, Null}
```

Comment: I think this only addresses two out of the three elements: reading the image and scaling the pixel values. It does not address the retrieval of the pixel positions.

Comment: Pixel positions are not necessary for the problem of replacing pixel values that exceed the threshold of 50 with 255. Pixel positions can be retrieved with PixelValuePositions.

Comment: You could amend your answer to address and benchmark the position part as well.

Answer (score 6):

As for part three of your operation, this seems to be rather zippy (about 800x faster than the `ReplacePart` line alone, with the additional benefit of shedding the `Position` part):

```
img = Clip[imgData, {0, 49}, {0, 255}];
```

Comment: Dear Yves, 
I have a MacBook Pro (Retina, Mid 2012), 2,7 GHz Intel Core i7, 16 GB 1600 MHz DDR3, NVIDIA GeForce GT 650M 1024 MB.
This is great with "Clip", but I also would need for the further analysis the positions of the pixels above the threshold ... is there also a trick ...

Comment: You might want to look at `PixelValuePositions` and `ReplacePixelValue` and related for a really performant solution.

Answer (score 5):

We focus on retrieving pixel positions meeting a criteria using Yves Klett and Simon Wood's answer. Let's run a test case using pixel values of 1 (this can easily be generalised to conditions such as pixel value >= 50). First generate some random coordinates in a 900 x 900 image.

```
xc = RandomSample[Range[900], 500];
yc = RandomSample[Range[900], 500];
```

Then generate a black image and colour the random points in white (i.e. set to 1).

```
img2 = ReplacePart[ConstantArray[0, {900, 900}], Transpose[{xc, yc}] -> 1];
```

Now time the various options.

```
t1 = Timing[ind1 = Position[img2, pix_ /; pix == 1];] // First
t2 = Timing[ind2 = PixelValuePositions[Image[img2], 1];] // First
t3 = Timing[ind3 = SparseArray[img2]["NonzeroPositions"];] // First
ind2 = Map[{901 - #[[1]], #[[2]]} &, Reverse[ind2, {2}]];
```

Notice that the image processing routine `PixelValuePositions[]` used image based coordinates rather than array based as for the other routines, hence the extra step to compute `ind2`.

First we check that all answers are now the same (the coordinates of the white pixels in array coordinates).

```
ind1 == ind2 == ind3
```

which gives

> True

and then the timing improvement on my MacBookPro.

```
t1/{t2, t3}
```

giving

> {28.96, 171.9}

So if the main information of interest is pixel positions you can get back about a factor of 30 in speed using the dedicated image processing routines and a factor of 170 using the SparseArray technique (which I believe is undocumented). Considering that `PixelValuePositions[]` is a dedicated function for this purpose there is definitely room for improvement here.

Comment: The only thing to add is the range for values >=50. Could probably be done with the third argument for `PixelValuePositions`.